# Google Chrome looses cached data at system failure

Tags: google-chrome, caching, html5-appcache

I am building an intreactive information kiosk for public use. Making it a web app in Chrome. It need to work offline. My solution is using the browsers application cache. Problem: Chrome looses all content in the application cache at crash/power failure. Is this normal behaviour?! Is there a way to hold the content in the event of system failure?

Edit 2012-12-19:
The content of the appcache is not lost, it is still there. But Chrome lost the reference to the data. If I start Chrome with the "--restore-last-session" flag it has the connection to the cached data. This is not a "pretty" solution though...

Clarification: The real problem is when Windows and Chrome starts after a power failure and the network connection is absent. Chrome acts as if there is nothing in the appcache and you get the "No network connection" error. I can't se why it works this way?